# Spring Data Rest: Tracking data changes in history tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I would like to track changes to my data using history tables using Spring Data Rest. My expected behavior is that for each transaction that changes data, an entry would automatically added to my history table. I am not sure, but I don't think it is valid to have transactions that span multiple requests when using services.

I currently have 2 options for this:

1) Use database triggers for the data - the disadvantage I see here is that currently, most of our manipulation is done through Java, and I don't see any way to do this via Java.

2) Use Annotated event handlers - we would create event handlers for each event for each table, to track the history, I am inclined to do this, but I am not sure if this is the correct way.

Which of the 2 options are better? Are there other options available as well?

Comment: Don't know if you have JPA/Hibernate in the back, but have a look at the hibernate envers project, if nothing else, for inspiration: http://envers.jboss.org/

Comment: Yes, we are using JPA/hibernate for this

Comment: I'd definitely recommend hibernate envers if you're using hibernate already. It's very easy to set up and works a treat @Audited
@AuditTable(value = "Transaction_Audit")
@Table(name = "[Transaction]")

Answer (score 4):

With Spring Data Rest you have an option to use [events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#events-chapter) do any any pre and post processing. I believe the original transaction boundary applies to any database operations in these events.

Answer (score 2):

Audit of operations with Envers [official site](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/)

Answer (score 1):

I know I am answering this years later but here is another approach:

Create a RepositoryEventHandler

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(Code.class)
public class CodesEventHandler {

    @Autowired
    private CodesRepository repository;

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleBeforeSave(Code c) {
        // backup the existing data to history (happens to be on the same table)
        Code newC = new Code();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(c, newC);
        CodeId newId = new CodeId();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(c.getCodeId(), newId);
        newC.setCodeId(newId);
        Date now = new Date();
        newC.getCodeId().setValidToTs(now);
        repository.save(newC);

        c.setValidFromTs(now);

    }

    @HandleBeforeDelete
    public void handleBeforeDelete(Code c) {
        // same as above but this time set the end timestamp to be now
    }
}
```